# Why does Vim on windows use \n for searching?

Tags: windows, vim, newline

So I was changing code from

```
foo()
{
```

to

```
foo() {
```

and I noticed that the searching pattern required me to search for `\n`, but when I tried to replace it with `\n` I got the `^@` character, and I had to instead replace with `\r`.

It seems strange to me that I search with `\n` and replace with `\r`, any idea why this might be?

For reference my solution was `:%s/\n\s*{/ {\r/g`

Comment: You think that's strange?  The way I used to fix the carriage return/line-feed problem when moving between Unix and Windows is to do `:%s/^V^M/^V^M/g`

Comment: @Paul I feel like this is a related problem.  Like its displaying one thing, searching against another thing and writing out a third.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The syntax for the search part and replacement part are arbitrarily different.  Some of the same codes are re-used to mean different things.  Yeah, it's confusing.

```
    | How to type         | In search, means:       | In replacement, means:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\n  | \n                  | End-of-line             | <Nul> 0x0
^@  | CTRL-V CTRL-J       | <Nul> 0x0               | <Nul> 0x0
\r  | \r                  | Carriage return 0xD     | "Break the line here"
^M  | CTRL-Enter          | Carriage return 0xD     | "Break the line here"
\^M | \ CTRL-V CTRL-ENTER | \ + carriage return 0xD | Carriage return 0xD
```

When searching, depending on your platform, the `0xD` may be hidden, considered part of "newline", so yeah... you can always return sanity to your files and force all of the carriage returns displayed by opening a file and doing:

```
:e ++ff=unix
```

Similarly when replacing, "break the line here" does different things depending on your platform.  It might insert `0xA` or `0xD 0xA` etc.

In case this isn't all already bad enough:

```
Technical detail:               *NL-used-for-Nul*
<Nul> characters in the file are stored as <NL> in memory.  In the display
they are shown as "^@".  The translation is done when reading and writing
files.  To match a <Nul> with a search pattern you can just enter CTRL-@ or
"CTRL-V 000".  This is probably just what you expect.  Internally the
character is replaced with a <NL> in the search pattern.  What is unusual is
that typing CTRL-V CTRL-J also inserts a <NL>, thus also searches for a <Nul>
in the file.  {Vi cannot handle <Nul> characters in the file at all}

                        *CR-used-for-NL*
When 'fileformat' is "mac", <NL> characters in the file are stored as <CR>
characters internally.  In the text they are shown as "^J".  Otherwise this
works similar to the usage of <NL> for a <Nul>.

When working with expression evaluation, a <NL> character in the pattern
matches a <NL> in the string.  The use of "\n" (backslash n) to match a <NL>
doesn't work there, it only works to match text in the buffer.
```

Unless dealing with literal `0x0` or `0xD` characters, it's agood a rule of thumb to always stick with `\n` for search and `\r` for replacement, as you've probably figured out.

See also:

```
:h /\n
:h /\r
:h s/\n
:h s/\r
:h s/\<CR>
```

Comment: What a clear table! Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is due to the fact that Unix-like operating systems like Linux use the newline (aka "linefeed") (0x0A) as the end of line marker, but Windows uses carriage return + newline (0x0D 0x0A).  vim is trying to do some sort of mapping to make the Windows two-byte end of line look like a single "end of line".

In a related note, the following command seems to convert a Unix-style file to a Windows one on a Windows machine, and convert a Windows-style file to a Unix one on a Unix machine:

`:%s/^V^M/^V^M/g`

where `^V` means hold the control key and press the V, and similarly `^M` means hold the control key and press M.

Comment: I'm familiar with the differences in newlines; what I'm interested in is why Vim seems to be partially masking this, and what rules it uses to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up understanding clearly or remembering all about `<NL>`, `<CR>` etc., which is too complex and not used frequently.
When I use them, just try.

---

In case this isn't all already bad enough:

`:h sub-replace-special`

```
        The special meaning is also used
        inside the third argument {sub} of the |substitute()| function
        with the following exceptions:
              . <CR> and \r inserts a carriage-return (CTRL-M).  
              . \<CR> does not have a special meaning. It's just one of \x.
              
              . A ~ inserts a tilde literally.
              . magic is always set without regard to 'magic'.
```