# LINUX End of Line

Tags: python, linux, ascii, vi

I am reading a ASCII file from LINUX(Debian) into Python CGI script where it is edited via a web page and then saved,

If I use a graphical text editor the edited and un-edited file appear the same and are corectly formatted.

Using vi the edited file contains `ctrl M` as the EOL marker and all lines rolled into one but the unedited file is correctly formatted. Using `:set List` in vi to see control characters the edited file remains as described above, but in the unedited file `$` appears as EOL marker.
I know LINUX EOL is ctrl 0x0D but what is the `$`?

Why does `$` format correctly and `ctrl M` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is displayed by `vi` (in certain modes). It is not in the file contents. You could use `od -cx yourfile` to check that.

Answer (score 1):

In vi, the `$` matches the EOL character. You can change the EOL character with `:set fileformat=XXX` as seen [here](http://www.jrwz.net/technical/vi/mytips.html#4). I'm not 100% sure that if you change the filetype that the `$` will match the new EOL as I haven't tried it. But that link contains information that will be handy for the rest of the answer.

The `^M` or `(CTRL-M)` character is [roughly equivalent to a carriage return](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~srg/LaTeX/howto.html).

From what you're saying, it sounds like the graphical text editor is using Mac-like EOL which is just a carriage return (CR) without the line feed. Hence the `^M` characters and all the lines rolled into one. If it was using Windows/DOS EOL, which is carriage return plus line feed (CR+LF), I would expect the `^M` characters but each line on it's own separate line.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim) explains how to get rid of the `^M` characters. I wouldn't use `dos2unix` since I'm not sure how it would handle having just the CR and not CR+LF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I wish I had seen it earlier as it would have saved me some time