# Converting multi line string to single line string in python

Tags: python, tesseract, multiline, python-tesseract

I am working with tesseract library and want my text from an image to be in a single line, without new lines(`"\n"`).

I tried to use `variable.replace("\n"," ")`, but it is not working. It just gives me the same multi line response.

Below is my code:

```
img = Image.open('maaan.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
kt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng')
kt.replace("\n", " ")
print(kt)
```

Thanks for the help btw :D

Comment: You should inspect your text in a hex editor then. Chances are you have other kind of line breaks in the text, such as ``\r``.

Answer (score 2):

Write `\n` as `raw string`, like :

```
my_variable = my_variable.replace(r"\n"," " )
```

try:

```
print(kt.replace(r"\n"," ")
```

Or,

```
kt = kt.replace(r"\n", " ")
print(kt)
```

Comment: it sadly doesn't work for me for some reason it only works when i use print(kt.replace("\n"," ") but what if i want to replace another char?

Comment: @Nisox, Please see updated answer. Hope, it will help you.

Comment: thanks it helped print(kt.replace) works fine but i will need to figure how to convert multiple characters that way !

Answer (score 0):

`kt.replace("\r", "\t")`

Visit this link, it has more explanation: [python convert multiline to single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004807/python-convert-multiline-to-single-line)