# store all the data in terminal to text file by tee command or equivalent tool

Tags: linux, tee

I learnt that a tee command will store the STDOUT to a file as well as outputs to terminal.

But, here the problem is every time I have to give tee command, for every command I give.

Is there any way or tool in linux, so that what ever I run in terminal, it should store the command as well as output.  (I used tee command in MySQL, where it will store all the commands and outputs to a file of that entire session. I am expecting a tool similar to this.)

Edit:
When I run `script -a log.txt`, I see ^M characters as well as ^[  and  ^] characters in log.txt file. I used various `dos2unix, :set ff=unix, :set ff=dos` commands, but they didn't helped me in removing these ^[, ^] characters. 
Is there any method, I can directly get the plain text file (with out these extra chars).

OS: RHEL 5

Comment: [`man script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping an interactive session to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812098/piping-an-interactive-session-to-a-file)

Comment: Most of the desktop consoles like 'konsole' in KDE and `gnome terminal` provide an option to save the entire scrollback for the terminal. For example the `Edit` menu in `konsole` provides the option to `Save History As...` which will prompt for a filename and save all lines to a file. Your `~/.bash_history` file should already have all the commands. If you want to do this on a `per-command` basis from within a script -- then you are stuck with `tee` if you want screen output in addition to redirection to a file.

Comment: David, in my terminal there is no option to save the session. I am using RHEL 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script command which writes everything on file

```
script -f log.txt
```

Comment: This is like what exactly I want. But, i am getting weird characters as stated in the question.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819707/why-does-the-script-command-generate-and-m-characters-and-how-to-remove-th

Answer (score -2):

you could use aliases like such `alias ls="ls;echo ls >>log"` so every time you run `ls` it runs `echo ls >>log` too.
But script would probably be better in this case, just dont go into vi while you are in script.

Comment: -1 Uh, what?  Please explain how you think this could be used to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It's the new method of teaching programming -- kinda like "new math", I just don't see it... I guess..