# Reason for ^M while executing a java program

Tags: java, linux, bash, operating-system

I am using java 1.7 and trilead ssh library to execute the commands in Linux environment.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import com.trilead.ssh2.ChannelCondition;
import com.trilead.ssh2.Connection;
import com.trilead.ssh2.Session;

public class TestSSH
{
    private static final String  ipAddress                        = "ipaddress";
    private static final String  username                         = "username";
    private static final String  password                         = "password";
    private static final int     port                             = 22;
    private static Connection    connection;
    private static Session       mySession;
    private static OutputStream  inStream;
    private static InputStream   outStream;
    private static InputStream   errStream;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
            String prompt = initPrompt();
    }

    private static String initPrompt()
        throws IOException
    {       
        boolean isAuthenticated = false;
        String myPrompt = "";
        connection = new Connection(ipAddress, port);
        connection.connect(null, 30 * 1000, 0);

        isAuthenticated =
                connection.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println(" Authenticated !....");
        mySession = connection.openSession();
        mySession.requestPTY("dumb", 256, 24, 0, 0, null);
        mySession.startShell();
        inStream = mySession.getStdin();
        outStream = mySession.getStdout();
        errStream = mySession.getStdout();
        try
        {
            writeInput(inStream, "ls -ltr /;echo [[COMMAND_EXIT_CODE=$?]];");
            flushOutput(inStream);

        int len = outStream.read(buffer);
        StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();

        if (len > 0)
            {
                    outputString.append(new String(buffer, 0, len, "utf-8"));
                    output.append(outputString.toString());
            }

    }

}
```

I am executing the the program in the Linux mahcine Redhat 6.4 OS( as localhost i.e source and destination are same) and the getting the below output.

```
output:
    com.xxx.yyy output: ^M
Last login: Fri Jun 12 09:19:03 2015 from x.x.x.x^M^M
prompt-1:~ # ^M
SC-1:~ # echo COMMAND^M
COMMAND^M
prompt-1:~ #
Fri Jun 12 09:19:03 2015 from x.x.x.x^M^M
prompt-1:~ # ^M
prompt-1:~ # echo COMMAND^M
COMMAND^M
prompt-1:~ #
```

I am expecting the output as without ^M(line feed) so that i can fetch the prompt expected output. Can anybody tell me the reason why ^M is appended in the output. I am not getting ^M in other machines. In other machines the occurence is very rare.

Is there any configuration i needs to be change in my OS to overcome this issue? 
Is there any thing i have to configure in java to overcome this?
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Any reason why you cannot simply parse out the `^M`?

Comment: @Tim parsing is different aspect but i want to know the reason behind this. Thanks

Comment: Similar answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim. The ^M will be the carriage return. What is System.lineSeparator() set to? You can see the Hex value by using System.out.println("Line sep: " + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(System.lineSeparator().getBytes()));

Comment: Please mention the reason why it is appending ^M for some scenarios

Answer (score -2):

You can try executing the below sed command in your Linux shell:

sed -n l  `your java code file`

you may find out there are some `\r` in your code, and I believe that is '^M'
I guess you wrote these codes on Windows OS where line separator is "\r\n" NOT "\n".