# php executable file not running

Tags: php, linux, terminal

I've looked at how composer is set up to run a php script by calling `composer` without issuing `php` manually and I tried to do this myself but it isn't working. I know this is probably asked before but I can't formulate a question to find it.

I have my file

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo 'teststring' . PHP_EOL;
```

when I issue `test` in the directory the file is located I get nothing, but if I do `php test` then I get "teststring" echoed out. The question is - how do I set it up so that I can execute the file directly?

I have given `x` permissions on the file.

Here is a sample output:

```
x@y:~/www/html/dev/Project$ ls
...
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data    53 сеп 22 12:34 test
...
x@y:~/www/html/dev/Project$ test
x@y:~/www/html/dev/Project$ php test
teststring
x@y:~/www/html/dev/Project$ which php
/usr/bin/php
x@y:~/www/html/dev/Project$
```

Comment: Your shebang line doesn't look ok to me. It should be something like `#!/usr/bin/env/php` or `#!/usr/bin/php` depending on where your executable lies.

Comment: @Havelock tried both your suggestions, still the same resullt. As I said I just copied that from composer.

Comment: Then you need to find where your executable php is. You can try with something like `find / -name php` or `locate php` or even maybe `whereis php`...

Comment: You should try to locate php executable by using which instead of whereis like so`$ which php`

Comment: My installation is pretty standard and php is located in `/usr/bin/php` but even if I change line 1 to `#!/usr/bin/php` I still get the same results, see the edit I will make shortly.

Comment: The problem you're facing is only about the way you're trying to execute the shell script, not about the path of php, you can execute it like so `./teststring` or using the full path of the script like so `~/www/html/dev/Project/teststring`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to locate php executable by using `which` instead of `whereis` like so

```
$ which php
```

... this command only searches for executables, while `whereis` tries to *guess* useful links, you can read more [here] (https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences)

Then just run it like so

`$ ./teststring`

You can read more about executing shell scripts here

[thegeekstuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/execute-shell-script/)

[tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)

Comment: Well that is not the case with composer, if you install it locally you can call `composer`,  That's what I'm interested in. Also if I call it with `./` notation I get `-bash: ./test: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
`. If I change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env php` I get `: No such file or directory`

Comment: My bad, let me check out this `composer` you speak of, I obviously know nothing about :)

Comment: It is not just composer, pretty much any library provides such functionality, you can also see `phpunit` for example, it is the same. Also laravel's `artisan` has the same `#!/usr/bin/env php`, you can see it [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan)

Comment: Hmm, the shell should interpret that php executable just fine though and that `/usr/bin/php^M` looks weird, you should discard the trailing ^M, [what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim) or [remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/)