# print and pexpect logging and reading the file

Tags: python

I am actually trying to write the commands and its output to a file and then read the file . The file is created , but for reading the file, it gives error as valueerror i/o operation. What am I missing here. ?

```
import pexpect
import time,sys
from StringIO import StringIO

telconn=pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.24.12.109')
telconn.logfile = sys.stdout
telconn.expect(":")
telconn.send("user" + "\r")
telconn.expect(":")
telconn.send("pass" + "\r\r\r\r\n\n\n")
telconn.expect("key to proceed.")
telconn.send ("\003")
telconn.expect("root>")
sys.stdout=open("test1.txt","w")

print "Telnet connection is done"

telconn.sendline('ls -al');
telconn.expect (['root>',pexpect.EOF])
ls = telconn.before

telconn.sendline('pwd');
telconn.expect (['root>',pexpect.EOF])
pwd = telconn.before

telconn.sendline('cli');
telconn.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
cli = telconn.before

telconn.sendline('\n\n');

telconn .sendline('exit');
telconn.close()

print ls
print pwd
print cli
print "Ended session"

sys.stdout.close()

sys.stdout = open("test1.txt", "r+")
str = sys.stdout.read();
print "Read String is : ", str
# Close opend file

print "Read String is : ", str
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: why use `sys.stdout` for reading? you can do `f = open("test1.txt", "r+")` and then `f.read()`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I changed it to f for reading mode. But I am getting the below error                                                                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sample.py", line 48, in ?
    print "Read String is : ", str
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Did you change every `sys.stdout` to f? I recommend you try this. Just change  `sys.stdout=open("test1.txt","w")` to `f=open("test1.txt","w")` and instead of printing use `f.write()`

Comment: changing to f.write will not give the output of unix ls and pwd commands and it writes only ls and pwd in test1.txt file . sys.stdout will write the output of ls and pwd into test1.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit (OP wants system call prints to file):

Save the standard output to some temp var, so just add:

```
prev_std = sys.stdout
```

before you do `sys.stdout=open("test1.txt","w")`.

After you are done and closed `sys.stdout`, restore the original one:

```
sys.stdout = prev_std
```

Comment: I understand that it is trying to write "Read String is : ", str" to a closed file.  I want to know how can I write  ls and pwd outputs to a file and then open that file , read it and print ?

Comment: I have edited my answer after you clarified your problem

Comment: Thank you. this is serving my purpose.  When I open the test1.txt file, it has ^M charector at every line, is there a way to avoid it in the file it writes ?

Comment: please refer to this:
[What does ^M character mean in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim),
anyway I would appreciate if you accept my answer and upvote it

Comment: Thanks Eli. I clicked on the check mark . i clicked on upvote, not sure if u r able to see it.,

Comment: Also, if there are double tabs in the output, the file takes it as only single tab. how can we avoid it ?