# Duplicate the output of bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the piece of code of my bash script, I want to get duplicate output of that script.

This is how my script runs
`#bash check_script -a used_memory`

Output is: `used_memory: 812632`

Desired Output: `used_memory: 812632 | used_memory: 812632`

```
get_vals() {
     metrics=`command -h $hostname -p $port -a $pass info | grep -w $opt_var | cut -d ':' -f2 > ${filename}`
}

output() {
get_vals
if [ -s ${filename} ];
then
   val1=`cat ${filename}`
   echo "$opt_var: $val1"
   # rm $filename;
    exit $ST_OK;
else
     echo "Parameter not found"
     exit $ST_UK
fi
}
```

But when i used `echo "$opt_var: $val1 | $opt_var: $val1"` the output become: `| used_memory: 812632`

`$opt_var` is an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when capturing results from `cat` with Windows-formatted text files. One way to circumvent this issue is to pipe your result to [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix), e.g.:

```
val1=`cat ${filename} | dos2unix`
```

Also, if you want to duplicate lines, you can use [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 | \1/'
```

Then pipe it to your `echo` command:

```
echo "$opt_var: $val1" | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 | \1/'
```

The sed expression works like that:

1. `'s/<before>/<after>/'` means that you want to substitute `<before>` with `<after>`
2. on the `<before>` side: `^.*$` is a regular expression meaning you get the entire line, `^\(.*\)$` is basically the same regex but you get the entire line *and* you capture everything (capturing is performed inside the `\(\)` expression)
3. on the `<after>` side: `\1 | \1` means you write the 1st captured expression (`\1`), then the space character, then the pipe character, then the space character and then the 1st captured expression again

So it captures your entire line and duplicates it with a "`|`" separator in the middle.

Comment: Getting error when i pipe it. `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command.` But when i install dos2unix and use `echo "$opt_var: $val1 | $opt_var: $val1"` it's working, although i am not using windows formatted text files.

Comment: @blaCkninJa Forgot the slash at the end. My bad.

Comment: @blaCkninJa if you open your file with `vi -b "${filename}"` do you see a `^M` character before the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, I found ^M end of line. What does it mean ?

Comment: @blaCkninJa  It means it is Windows-formatted :) More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim#5843561

Comment: `tr -d '\r'` removes any [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Comment: Thank you. How can i understand the `sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 | \1/'` ? Any guide to learn these regex.

Comment: @blaCkninJa I edited the answer to include more details.