# Weird character in a commit.template of git

Tags: javascript, git

I have setted a **commit.template** and it is working correctly, although it shows a weird character **^M** in all the lines even the ones with #.
I would like to remove it, because it is really annoying.

I have been surfing on internet tryng to find information about it, but, I couldn´t find anything clear.

All the information I have found here, it is about, how to set a **commit.template or a hook**, but nothing linked with my question. I gonna keep searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does ^M character mean in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim)

Comment: @Good could I answer my own question.The asnwer you suggested it is not the same because it is not related with commit.template.

Comment: I have found the way to solve it out.

Comment: If you want to know why it appears this charcter in Vim, go to here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim

Comment: But, if you did your own commit-template.txt to set it on git and you got this character  **(^M**) when you do your commits the easiest way to avoid it, it is to do your commit-template.txt with Vim instead of memo pad, because if you use memo pad of windows, you will have the annoying **(^M**)