# vim command to remove extraneous characters?

Tags: vim

I used to know a vim command sequence where I would remove all the non-printable extraneous characters in a file, like `^M` on Windows files that ended up with `col -xb`, but I can't recall the keyboard sequence before I enter the `col -xb` command to say "do this from top-to-bottom of file." Does this ring a bell to anybody?

Comment: Do you mean to ask what is the syntax for calling an external command from within Vim and passing it the contents of the buffer? Then the answer is `:%!col -xb` (`:` for entering the ex-command mode as usual, `%` for selecting all lines (you can also write other ranges, like `100,150` for the lines 100 to 150) and `!` for piping it through an external command.

Comment: That's it. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%!col -xb
```

`:` enters the ex-command mode as usual,`%` selects all lines (you can also write other ranges, like `100,150` for lines 100 to 150) and `!` pipes them through an external command.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command in vim:
`:set fileformat=unix`
it worked for me, and also check out: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: None of those worked form me, I tried most of them before posting. This is not an answer to the specific question though, but thanks.

Comment: If your problem is that Vim displays `^M` at the end of every line, that is because your file follows DOS/Windows’ convention (i.e. “CR LF”) for line endings and Vim wrongly interprets it as the Unix/Linux convention (i.e. “LF”), which leaves one uninterpreted CR character before every line ending. To just make them disappear from display, have Vim re-interpret the file correctly with `:e ++ff=dos`. If *after that*, you also want to actually remove them from the file, then run `:set ff=unix` (as advised by this answer) and save your buffer. This recodes the file.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim) for many more ways of dealing with / getting rid of CR LF in Vim.